# No Touch feedback on recyclerview when using ripple effect library

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

Here is my main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
        android:elevation="7sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecycleView"
            android:layout_width="288dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my item_row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/ripple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/rowText" />
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using the libray https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

When I am not using the library the click is working fine but when using the library I did not receive any touch feedback.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your **item_row.xml** with the **MaterialRippleLayout**. Basically set it as your parent layout to receive the click from the user. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/ripple"
   android:paddingTop="8dp"
   android:paddingBottom="8dp"
   android:background="#ffffff"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:mrl_rippleColor="#80000000"
   app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/rowText" />

</LinearLayout>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```